# Firebase deploy slow performance

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I hosted an angular project of 7mb size using Firebase host and it takes long for getting loaded for users. Is that because 7mb is considered large size for a website ?

Comment: Not really. But that depends a lot on what those 7MB consists of and how much of that you download to the user on their first visit. Waterfall charts are usually a good way to start investigating the performance of web site loading.

Comment: I have cloud functions and their deploy IS REALLY SLOW. Every deploy takes several minutes (4-5) and I don't know how to test my functions locally :-/